# How do I achieve the color tone effect in this sample photo in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, color, photo-editing

In post-processing, how do i achieve a high dynamic range, but low local contrast, monotone (but not necessarily grayscale) effect for photos? An example would be this ["li river"](http://foureyes.deviantart.com/art/li-river-63195216) shot, which has a light blue monotone and a soft, low-contrast feel, but fairly high overall dynamic range? Is such an effect possible using Photoshop?

Comment: What 'effect' in the photo do you want? Describe the quality you're trying to get to.

Comment: I would like to know how he achieved the color tone using photoshop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a simple desaturation, followed by a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer set to Colorize. Probably a bit of Levels/Curves adjustment for contrast.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like it could also be a gradient map. Just set the dark end of the gradient to a slightly bluish hue. Gradient maps are often used to warm up black and white photos using a slightly "chocolatey" dark.